# Сортировка даты/время датафрейм

Tags: python, dataframe

Как отсортировать в dataframe дату и время в таком примере как внизу?
([пример .csv тут](https://we.tl/t-IwGMzALfXg))
Примечательно, что время здесь от '20:00:00' до '23:59:00' и от '00:00:00' до '06:00:00', тоесть 2/4/2022 0:29:00 будет меньше чем 2/4/2022 22:17:00

```
df = 

Date        Time
2/2/2022    23:34:00
2/3/2022    1:49:00
2/3/2022    3:19:00
2/4/2022    22:17:00
2/1/2022    22:56:00
2/3/2022    1:54:00
2/4/2022    0:29:00
2/4/2022    22:49:00
2/4/2022    22:28:00
```

Пример результата:

```
df = 

Date        Time
2/1/2022    22:56:00
2/2/2022    23:34:00
2/3/2022    1:49:00
2/3/2022    1:54:00
2/3/2022    3:19:00
2/4/2022    0:29:00
2/4/2022    22:17:00
2/4/2022    22:28:00
2/4/2022    22:49:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы всегда можете получить из ваших исходных данных колонку с типом datetime, и, затем, просто отсортировать датафрейм по этой колонке:

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values("datetime").drop(columns="datetime")
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

теперь df у вас:

```
       Date      Time
0  2/1/2022  22:56:00
1  2/2/2022  23:34:00
2  2/3/2022   1:49:00
3  2/3/2022   1:54:00
4  2/3/2022   3:19:00
5  2/4/2022   0:29:00
6  2/4/2022  22:17:00
7  2/4/2022  22:28:00
8  2/4/2022  22:49:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы таких проблем не возникало лучше даты и время сразу приводить к типу datetime. Это можно сделать прямо во время чтения файла, примерно так:

```
df = pd.read_csv('11.csv', parse_dates={'dt':[0,1]})
df.sort_values('dt', inplace=True)
'''
                   dt
4 2022-02-01 22:56:00
0 2022-02-02 23:34:00
1 2022-02-03 01:49:00
5 2022-02-03 01:54:00
2 2022-02-03 03:19:00
6 2022-02-04 00:29:00
3 2022-02-04 22:17:00
8 2022-02-04 22:28:00
7 2022-02-04 22:49:00
```

Если обязательно нужно разделить дату и время на разные колонки, то в принципе, примерно так это тоже можно сделать:

```
df['dt'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'date':x.date(), 'time':x.time()}))
'''
         date      time
4  2022-02-01  22:56:00
0  2022-02-02  23:34:00
1  2022-02-03  01:49:00
5  2022-02-03  01:54:00
2  2022-02-03  03:19:00
6  2022-02-04  00:29:00
3  2022-02-04  22:17:00
8  2022-02-04  22:28:00
7  2022-02-04  22:49:00
```